# Navigation Menu That Shows/Hides On Rollover and Click

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I would like to know if its possible to have a CSS-only navigation menu that toggles to shows/hides other divs when a navigation element is clicked or rolled-over?

Here is an example of what I mean: http://www.johnlewis.com

Note that on that site, the CSS hover navigation menu works even with Javascript disabled.

**Question 1:** are there any tutorials or examples available of how to create this type of menu? I have looked and seen some tab-based menu tutorials but they don't look anything like this.

**Question 2:** Can I replicate the example but also have the sub-menu appear when a top-level menu item is clicked (not just rolled-over). This would be helpful for tablet users who can't perform rollovers. On the first click I'd like the sub-menu to appear. On the second click of the same top-level item, I'd like it to go to that actual link. Is this going to require JS/JQuery or can it be done CSS only as well?

I don't mind using a JQuery solution but would prefer a CSS solution if possible. I just need some pointers, not a full solution of course.

Comment: Not sure why you added the jQuery tag to your question when you're looking for a CSS-only solution. If this was done in error, you may want to remove that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @serlite apologies for the confusion. i have updated my question. basically i don't mind using JQuery/JS to achieve what I want, but my first priority to understand how to make such a menu. I think the single-click/double-click functionality will HAVE to be in JS/JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using just CSS with the `:hover` pseudo-selector for the parent div, and also adding a class when you click on it (for tablets). For a quick example, you'd want something like this for the structure:

```
<div class="nav-header">
    <h3>My Header</h3>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <!-- Your sub menu code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS would look something like this:

```
div.nav-header div.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

div.nav-header:hover div.sub-menu, div.nav-header.clicked div.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    /* your positioning code */
}
```

Then in the click event handler:

```
function click_handler(eventArgs) {
    // Often, jQuery click event targets are the children of the element you actually want.
    var $navHeader = $(eventArgs.target).hasClass('nav-header') ? $(eventArgs.target) : $(event.target).parents('div.nav-header');

    if ( $navHeader.hasClass('clicked') ) {
        window.location.href = "/yourUrl";
    } else {
        $navHeader.addClass('clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! could you suggest on how to make the first click apply the .clicked toggle, but the second click should go to a page?

Comment: Sorry; I misread your question the first time around; I've updated the code.